# How to Replace DLL Reference in Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dll

A code sample I am referencing also provides updated DLL's to reference in the sample project. When I delete the current DLLs and then add a reference to the new versions, I get an error saying `A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project.` Not sure what this means, the assemblies are specifically for a windows phone project and are meant to be as updates/replacements to fix some bug issues.

Answer (score 0):

The DLL to be referenced must be Unblocked beforehand. Right Click on the DLL, go to the properties option, then select Unblock. This must be done one at a time for each DLL to be added.